# Does using a ceiling fan pull chain cause more wear than using a light switch?

Tags: ceiling-fan

Does it matter if you always use the light switch to turn the fan off instead of using the pull chain? Basically every time someone flips the light switch on or off the fan turns on or off. Does this wear out the motor any faster or anything?

Comment: Maybe marginally, but in my experience the pull chain switches are about the only thing I've ever needed to replace on a ceiling fan.

Comment: I think it would depend on the quality of the switches.

Comment: An issue not related to wear is increased energy costs due to cycling the fan motor on and off needlessly. Once running, ceiling fans are very efficient. Each time you turn it on from stopped there is increased power consumption due to initial inrush current of inducted load. I have read that it is cheaper to just leave it on all day than to switch it on and off more than a couple times.

Comment: That's not true at all.  It is a common rationalization/excuse/meme started by slobs who can't be bothered turning things off when they're done with them.  I've got one landscaper who leaves 2000W of shop lighting on all day while he's out... same logic.  **Yes, there is inrush current but it's not that much**. Honestly if 3 seconds of startup current was the same as 3 hours of cruise current, that means startup current is 3600 times normal.  That would not only *instantly vaporize* the fan motor, but the branch circuit wires as well.  Obviously that ain't so!

Answer (score 1):

There is no additional wear on the motor either way.

Obviously, there will be wear on whichever switch you use.